# C++ data changing with no apparent reason

Tags: c++

I have the following method:

```
void Polygon::expand() {
    int newSize = max * 2;
    printArray(array, current);
    Point* newArray = new Point[newSize];
    printArray(array, current);
    for (int i = 0; i <= current; i++) {
            newArray[i] = array[i];
    }
    delete[] this->array;
    array = newArray;
    max = newSize;
}
```

`printArray` is for debugging and is also very simple:

```
void printArray(Point* array, int size) {
    cout << "array\n==========" << endl;
    for (int i=0; i<=size; i++) {
            cout << array[i] << ": " << array[i].getX() << ", " << array[i].getY() << endl;
    }
}
```

The method is trying to expand array, which is a class member of type `Point*`. The weird thing is the prints I get when running this:

> array
>    ==========
>    (0,0): 0, 0
>    (1,1): 1, 1
>    (2,2): 2, 2
>    (3,3): 3, 3
>    array
>    ==========
>    (0,0): 0, 0
>    (1,1): 1, 1
>    (2,2): 2, 2
>    (3,5.58294e-322): 3, 5.58294e-322

For some reason the last `Point` in array changes, even though I haven't touched it between the prints! Any idea on what can cause that?

Answer (score 7):

When you start your indexing from `0` (as in C and C++) you stop at one less than the `size`. So, do:

```
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) // not <=
```

This is a classic off-by-one error (and you're invoking UB).

Comment: I don't see how this can be what causing different points to be printed, even if I'm off by one.

Comment: When you invoke UB, as you have, more than once, you cannot expect any sane output. Fix your code and then give it another shot. Remember we don't even know what `getX`, `getY` does. So, I'd suggest you check these too.

Comment: In this case, `current` is kept as the largest index, not the actual size.

Comment: Undefined behavior. IOW, this is something (typically an operation whose semantics are not defined by the standard) which when invoked makes reasoning about your code impossible.